# Google App Scripts, get number of numbered list

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to modify a Google Docs containing a built-in nested numbered list. To do this I need to find the number associated with a particular sentence. For example:

(Sorry hard to format this)

**List In Google Docs:**

1. This is a list
2. This is an item in the list

2.1. This is a nested item
2.1.1. This is another

2.1.1.1. And a third

**Input:** And a third

**Expected output:** 2.1.1.1.

Here's a general idea of the code I have:

```
body.getListItems().forEach((item) => {
    if (item.getText() === textToFind) {
        return (item.getNumber())
}
 });;
```

What would I use in place of item.getNumber()?